# Structure with attribute like-c in Python

Tags: python, c, padding

I want to create something like structure in C but in Python. Specifically I want to sth like that:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) 
{
    float x[4];
    uint8 y;
    int z;
} structName;
```

in Python. I read somewhere that I can use named tuple but want to avoid padding and I don't know how to do it in Python. Can anyone show me how to do that? I will use it in UDP communication.

Comment: Python is a more high-level language than C. There are no direct analogues. You might wanna check out `dataclass` or `namedtuple`

Comment: Please clarify *exactly* what you need. Considering ``struct`` as data layout, [``struct``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) is appropriate. Considering ``struct`` as data abstraction, a ``dict``, ``class``, ``namedtuple``, ``dataclass`` or similar is appropriate. Considering ``struct`` as serialisation basis, a function that formats ``bytes`` might be suitable.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi post this as the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to serialize (ex:save into file or send trough network) then, you should check out [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library basically you can define how to save your data, how many bytes and which order.

You can use a class in python to represent your struct and add two function for pack it into smaller binary data and unpack it from it if you need it again

Your example should be:

```
import struct

class StructName():
    def __init__(self, xs=None, y=None, z=None):
        self.xs = xs
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def pack(self):
        return struct.pack("!4fBi", *self.xs, self.y, self.z)

    def unpack(self, packed_bytes):
        *self.xs, self.y, self.z = struct.unpack("!4fBi", packed_bytes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = StructName([1.0, 0.5, 2.0, 0.], 255, 42)
    tmp = StructName()
    bytedata = s.pack()
    print("s", s.xs, s.y, s.z) # s [1.0, 0.5, 2.0, 0.0] 255 42
    print(len(bytedata), bytedata) # 21 b'\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00?\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00'
    tmp.unpack(bytedata)  # fill data into tmp class
    tmp.xs[0] = 42.5
    print("tmp", tmp.xs, tmp.y, tmp.z) # tmp [42.5, 0.5, 2.0, 0.0] 255 42
```

The format string in the `pack` and `unpack` function is "!4fBi" where:

- ! - use network byte order (bigendian)
- 4f - four float (4*4 byte)
- B - one unsigned char (1 byte)
- i - one signed integer (4 byte)

For more check out this section: [Format Characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I want to ask what means that '*' before self.xs

Comment: @KrysPy the '\*' will pack values from the result of the `struct.unpack` function into a list, except for the last two value those will be assigned to `y` and `z`. one example:
`*ls, last = (1, 2, 3, 4)` in this case the `last` will be `4` and the `ls` equals `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: One more question. Can I use in format string my own class object? For example when I create class in one module and then I want to get in structure data of this type (type of this new created class).

Comment: @KrysPy It's hard for me to understand what is your exact question. If you want to use this class in multiple modules you should move it into a separate module (like: **models.py** or **data_structures.py**) and import it from there into those modules in which you want to use them. In the format string you can only use those characters  described in the documentation of `struct`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters

Comment: Okay, sorry for incomprehensible questions, it hard to explain this but you have already help me a lot. Thank you one more time.

Comment: I have one more problem with this and maybe you will know. I have in my 'data structure' packed a few lists but unpack method can take only one starred argument. So when I packed data and then I want to unpack to this to specify variables (still a few list) I can't to this. Do you have any idea how to handle this? How to unpack bytes data to more than one list. My format string: '<I7f7f7f3f4ffI'

Comment: I see some possible solution to this, but none of them are oneliners, the most simplest: get values as one list and use indexing on it to slice it, like this: `ls = unpack('<I7f7f7f3f4ffI', data); i7 = ls[:7]; f7 = ls[7:14]; f7_2 = ls[14:21]; f3 = ls[21:24];...`

Comment: I added (below )a general answer to this question. you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to a comment in the comment section of the accepted answer

```
import re
import struct


def get_values_from_binary(format_str, bin_data):
    val_regex = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]([0-9]+)?")
    ls = struct.unpack(format_str, bin_data)
    res = []
    i = 0
    for m in val_regex.finditer(format_str):
        groups = m.groups()
        current_length = 1
        if groups is not None and groups[0] is not None:
            current_length = int(groups[0])
        res.append(ls[i:i + current_length])
        i += current_length
    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f_str = "<I7f7f7f3f4ffI"
    data = [0]*7 + [0.3]*7 + [0.5]*7 + [0.9]*3 + [1.0]*4 + [2.5, 3.5, 1]
    print(data)
    bindata = struct.pack(f_str, *data)
    unpacked_data = get_values_from_binary(f_str, bindata)
    print(unpacked_data)
```

Comment: I finally done this in unpack method. I just assigned the appropriate elements from tuple which is generated after unpacking to attributes in class and for it's work. Thank you very much for all your help!